# how to get the previous 3 months in php

Tags: php

how to get the previous 3 months in php ex(If i say DEC.. It should display the previous 3 months i.e., OCT NOV DEC)

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function like this:

```
echo date('M', strtotime('-3 month'));
```

So you specify previous dates with minus sign.

```
echo date('M', strtotime('0 month'));
echo date('M', strtotime('-1 month'));
echo date('M', strtotime('-2 month'));
echo date('M', strtotime('-3 month'));
```

**Results:**

```
Dec
Nov
Oct
Sep
```

---

You can do the same if you are using a loop like this:

```
for ($i = -3; $i <= 0; $i++){
  echo date('M', strtotime("$i month"));
}
```

**Results:**

```
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec
```

---

Check out the documentation too see many other friendly date and time keywords `strtotime` supports:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: $month = date('M');
  $year = date('Y');
  $no_of_mnths = date('n',strtotime("-2 months"));
  $remaining_months = (12 - $no_of_mnths)."\r\n";
  $tot = $remaining_months+1; 
  for($j=0;$j<$tot;$j++){                         echo date('M',strtotime(''.$no_of_mnths.' months'));            $no_of_mnths++;   
  }

Answer (score 3):

Voted answer is almost correct.

Correct solution is:

```
for ($i = -3; $i <= 0; $i++){
   echo date('M', strtotime("$i month", strtotime(date("Y-m-15"))));
}
```

Explain: [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) default implementation is:

```
date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] ) : string
```

As you can see there is timestamp with default value of: time().

Last say today is 31th March.

Because there is no 31th Feb

```
echo date('M', strtotime("-1 month"));
```

will return March

On the other hand:

```
echo date('M', strtotime("+1 month"));
```

will return May (April will be skipped).

Because of that issue we have to setup timestamp value which is a safe date.
Every date between 1-28 is safe because every month have got that date. In my example I had choose 15th day of month.

Comment: Good boy! I ran into the problem you solved in your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
    $month = date('M');
    $year = date('Y');
    $no_of_mnths = date('n',strtotime("-2 months"));
    $remaining_months = (12 - $no_of_mnths)."\r\n";
    $tot = $remaining_months+1; 
    for($j=0;$j<$tot;$j++){
            echo  date('M',strtotime(''.$no_of_mnths.' months'))        
            $no_of_mnths++;         
    }
```

Comment: Sry am a new bee to Stack Overflow

Comment: for ($i = -2; $i <= 0; $i++){
  echo date('M', strtotime("$i month"));
}

Answer (score -1):

This may help you`

```
<?php
    $date = explode("-", "2016-08-31");
   if($date[2]== "01"){$days = "-0 days";}else{$days = "-1 days";}
        $time = strtotime($days, mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0]));
        $MTD = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('0 month'));
        $M1 = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('-1 month'));
        $M2 = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('-2 month'));
        $M3 = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('-3 month'));    
$rng = array();
        $rng[$MTD] = strftime("%B, %Y", strtotime(" ", $time));
        $rng[$M1] = strftime("%B, %Y", strtotime("first day of previous month",    $time));
        $rng[$M2] = strftime("%B, %Y", strtotime("-2 months", $time));
        $rng[$M3] = strftime("%B, %Y", strtotime("-3 months", $time));
?>
```

Here $MTD ,$M1,$M2,$M3 will give date in the form of "dd-mm-yyyy" and $rng[$MTD], $rng[$M1],$rng[$M2],$rng[$M3] give date in the form of"Name of Month,year" => (i.e August,2016)