# Custom Month and Year inside php for-loop

Tags: php, datetime, for-loop

I saw this question: 
[how to get the previous 3 months in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497199/how-to-get-the-previous-3-months-in-php)

My question is.. How do i output from a custom month. 
I want to start from `Mar 2018` (or any `M Y` user inputs) and it should output the next `3` (or any number user inputs) months. 
Ex: `Mar`, `Apr`, `May`

The code below is from current month and year.

```
// current month: Aug 2018
for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
    $x = strtotime("$i month");
    echo $dte = date('M Y', $x);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

And the output is

```
Aug 2018
Sep 2018
Oct 2018
```

Comment: Can you try changing as below where you can take dynamic Month and year and get result 

$effective_date = "MAR 2018";
$x = strtotime("$i month",strtotime($effective_date));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [increment date by one month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870295/increment-date-by-one-month)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and increment using a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object:

```
// Assuming these are the user inputs
$month = 11;
$year = 2015;

// We create a new object with year and month format
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y m', $year . ' ' . $month);


for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
    // Output the month and year
    echo $date->format('m Y') . '<br>';

    // Add 1 month to the date
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
}
```

Output:

> 11 2015
>   12 2015
>   01 2016

Documentation:

- [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
- [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)
- [DateTime::add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes, this automatically changes the year (tested starting from `Dec 2015` with PHP 7.2: working).

Comment: Of course it does. You're using`DateInterval`. I take back my previous comment :-) +1 for using `DateTime` and `DateInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this as below it will give you as expected see the below code

```
    // current month: Aug 2018
  $effective_date = "MAR 2018";
for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
    $x = strtotime("$i month",strtotime($effective_date));
    echo $dte = date('M Y', $x);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be also helpful:

```
<?php
$month = 11;
$year  = 2017;
$count = 15;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $month++;
    if ($month > 12) {
        $month = 1;
        $year++;    
    }   
    $x = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', $year.'-'.$month);
    echo $x->format('m-Y');
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Output:

```
12-2017
01-2018
02-2018
03-2018
04-2018
05-2018
06-2018
07-2018
08-2018
09-2018
10-2018
11-2018
12-2018
01-2019
02-2019
```

Comment: Why 15 results ? Why using `DateTime` but adding months manually instead of using [`DateTime::add / date_add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: @AymDev Just another way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for add nth Days, Months and Years

```
$n = 2;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++){
    $d = strtotime("$i days");
    $x = strtotime("$i month");
    $y = strtotime("$i year");
    echo "Dates : ".$dates = date('d M Y', "+$d days");
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Months : ".$months = date('M Y', "+$x months");
    echo '<br>';
    echo "Years : ".$years = date('Y', "+$y years");
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the date with [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

Check this [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hbk3-qq5z)

```
<?php
$currMonth = 11;
$currYear  = 2017;
$count = 15;
$currentYear = date('M Y',strtotime($currYear.'-'.$currMonth));
echo $currentYear.'<br>';
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $currMonth++;
    if ($currMonth > 12) {
        $currMonth = 1;
        $currYear++;    
    }   
    $newMonthandYear = date('M Y',strtotime($currYear.'-'.$currMonth));
    echo $newMonthandYear.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$year = date('Y');

//start at march 
$startMonth = 7;

//go forwards 2 months
$stepForwards = 22;    

for ($i = $startMonth; $i <= $stepForwards; $i++){

    if($i > 12 ) {

        $month = $i % 12 == 0 ?  12 : $i % 12;

    }
    else {

       $month = $i;

    }

    echo date("M Y", strtotime(date($year.'-'.$month.'-1'))) . "<br/>";

    if($month == 12) {

        $year++;

        echo "<br/>";

    }

}
```

Comment: This does not output anything as `$startMonth` is already bigger than `$stepForwards`