# Getting the three previous months in PHP is showing the same result

Tags: php, date

I need the three previous months from the current month.

I got this code from Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497199/how-to-get-the-previous-3-months-in-php):

```
  echo date('M Y', strtotime('-0 month'));
  echo date('M Y', strtotime('-1 month'));
  echo date('M Y', strtotime('-2 month'));
  echo date('M Y', strtotime('-3 month'));
```

The result is supposed to be:

```
Mar 2020
Feb 2020
Jan 2020
Dec 2019
```

But, I'm getting:

```
Mar 2020
Mar 2020
Jan 2020
Dec 2019
```

What's the problem? Is it because of the leap year in February?

Comment: *"I got this code from stackoverflow"* - Where from exactly? What's the URL for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497199/how-to-get-the-previous-3-months-in-php - this.

Comment: just check the most recent reply on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60928778/1891891 I think it explain this phenomenon:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the previous 3 months in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497199/how-to-get-the-previous-3-months-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also new to this concept, but this is what I found and it seems to work.

When you use `strtotime('-1 month')`, you would get February 31. This day doesn't exist, so that's probably what causes the issue.

I found this format that would get the first day of the month, that should fix the problem. It might not be the cleanest way to do it, but this seems to work.

```
  echo date('M Y', strtotime('first day of -0 month'));
  echo date('M Y', strtotime('first day of -1 month'));
  echo date('M Y', strtotime('first day of -2 month'));
  echo date('M Y', strtotime('first day of -3 month'));
```

By writing "first day of" before the -* month, you will grab the first day instead.

Check out *[Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/datetime.formats.relative)* where you can find all the formats you can use.

Answer (score 1):

> *"is it because of the leap year february?'* - Yes it does have something to do with it.

[Per the manual on `strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

from [user contributed note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#92600):

> Depending on the day of the month, you may get a different response.  For a non-leap year, you'll get March if the *current day of the month* is the 29th, 30th or 31st.  If it's a leap year, you'll get March on the 30th or 31st of the month.  The same thing will happen on the 31st of any month when you pass in the name of any month with less than 31 days.  This happens because the strtotime() function will fill in missing parts from the current day.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suggest you to use the DateTime library of PHP.

Like this:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$today->modify('last day of previous month');
echo $today->format('M') . '\n';
$today->modify('last day of previous month');
echo $today->format('M') . '\n';
$today->modify('last day of previous month');
echo $today->format('M') . '\n';
```

You will have these answers:

```
Feb
Jan
Dev
```

For more details, see *[DateTime::modify](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.modify.php)*